In uBlock Origin, how to block a specific domain without all its subdomains?
Given the domain example.com for example, I want to write a user rule to block everything (document, or js/css/image resources) from the exact domain example.com only, without blocking all its subdomains (i.e. cdn.example.com, blog.example.com, app.example.com should not be blocked).
The || syntax won't do because it will block all subdomains:
||example.com$all

! Now even subdomains like blog.example.com are blocked, which is I don't want

I have also tried using pipe syntax, but this could not be recognized by the uBlock Origin:
|example.com^


||example.com^$document

This rule will block requests to example.com but not its subdomains like sub.example.com. To add this rule, go to the uBlock Origin dashboard, click on the "My Filters" tab, and paste the rule there. After adding it, click "Apply changes."
